# Unable to allocate CUDA device memory for cufftComplex data type

Tags: c, cuda, cufft

I am trying to allocate a cufftComplex array into memory on a CUDA device (GEFORCE GTX 1080) using the following code:

```
cufftComplex *d_in, *d_out;
int ds = sizeof(cufftComplex) * width * height;
CUResult test_din = cuMemAlloc((void**)&d_in, ds);
CUResult test_dout = cuMemAlloc((void**)&d_out, ds);
printf("test_din:  %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(test_din));
printf("test_dout:  %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(test_dout));
```

When I run this code the error that I get is:

> test_din:  initialization error
>
> test_dout:  initialization error

When I compile the code I do get a warning about using void** but all the examples of cufft that I've seen, including the code samples that come with Cuda 9.1, include the void** type cast.  The warning is worded as follows:

> /usr/local/cuda/include/cuda.h:90:49: note: expected 'CUdeviceptr *' but argument is of type 'void **'

Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: why are you mixing the CUDA driver API with the CUDA runtime API?  I would strongly encourage beginners to just use the CUDA runtime API.  For example, `cudaGetErrorString` does not expect an argument of type `CUResult`.  As another example, it's perfectly fine to call `cudaMalloc` (runtime API)  at the very beginning of your program, but it's not OK to call `cuMemAlloc` (driver API) without first doing `cuInit()` and probably also establishing a CUDA context.  `cudaXXX()` is runtime API.  `cuXXX()` is driver API.  Most codes should not need to mix the two.

Comment: @Robert Crovella:  I am working off of different examples that use different commands so that would be why.  I will try replacing with cudaMalloc and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cuMemAlloc` is from the CUDA driver API.

If you study any proper driver API programs, you will find that one of the first things you need to do is to issue:

```
cuInit();
```

to start using CUDA.  Perhaps you have not done that (you are supposed to provide a MCVE).  That is a likely reason for this particular error.

You will run into other disconnects between the CUDA driver API and CUDA runtime API if you intermix the two.  It should not be necessary for most codes, and I don't recommend it for beginners.

Study sample codes to learn how to use one or the other.  For example, study the [vectorAdd](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#vector-addition) sample code to learn the basics of a [CUDA runtime API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html) program.  Study the corresponding [vectorAddDrv](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#vector-addition-driver-api) to learn the basics of a [CUDA driver API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/index.html) program.

The easiest fix here is probably just to replace your calls to `cuMemAlloc` with `cudaMalloc`:

```
cufftComplex *d_in, *d_out;
int ds = sizeof(cufftComplex) * width * height;
cudaError_t test_din = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_in, ds);
cudaError_t test_dout = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_out, ds);
printf("test_din:  %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(test_din));
printf("test_dout:  %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(test_dout));
```

Comment: That fixed it Thank You!